# Understanding how software accumulates memory in system

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Lately I've been trying to understand and track down a nasty memory leak in my software. To do this, I started to monitor memory usage over long periods of time to try to figure out if there is any pattern that would serve as a clue to understand this issue.

In the graphic bellow, the virtual memory is drawn in purple and the % of CPU memory in green, the x-axis represent time in seconds.

[image: Memory accumulation]

There are some big spikes that occur when a video streaming feature is activated, but this doesn't seem to be an issue since the software seems to be able to clear these.

Around second 7500 there is a big drop because of a stand-by feature of the system that was activated for a few seconds. After the system returns to normal, it clears some memory that was accumulated from before.. so far this makes sense. The thing I can't understand is that, if the amount of stored memory decreases, why doesn't the %Mem also decrease? In this case, it is actually increasing.

There is not a clear correlation between %Mem and virtual memory usage. Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that Virtual Memory is not actually related to %MEM, since it is stored in the hard-drive and swapped to RAM when a process needs it. The memory of a process that is related to the %MEM is the RSS (Resident Set Size), which is the memory that is stored in the RAM.

In the next graphic I monitored RSS instead, and the correlation is obvious.

[image]